# how can i dynamic update Datasource.groovy file

Tags: grails

in a grails project, there will a file named `DataSource.groovy`. Such as follows:

```
dataSource {
  pooled = true
  driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
  username = "sa"
  password = ""
}

mongodb {
  host = 127.0.0.1// adjust this according to your settings
  port = 27017
  databaseName = 'test'
  username = 'user'  // database user and password, if server requires authentication
  password = 's3cret' 
}
```

My question is that how can I set for example `mongodb.host` dynamically at run time.

Comment: why do you need dynamic hosts?

Answer (score 1):

If you have different MongoDB Hosts, you can set up different environments for development, test, and production using the `environments` closure in your `DataSource.groovy`.

In your example above, let's say that you are using `localhost 127.0.0.1` for development and `mongo-prodserver` for production

```
environments {
   development {
       grails {
           mongo {
               host = "127.0.0.1"
               port = 27017
               username = "user"
               password= "s3cret"
               databaseName = "test"
           }
       }
   }
   production {
       grails {
           mongo {
               host = "mongo-prodserver"
               port = 27017
               username = "user"
               password= "s3cret"
               databaseName = "prod"
           }
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

Here is the link to [Grails Doc on DataSources and Environments](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSourcesAndEnvironments).

Comment: thanks a lot,I am sorry ,I mean that "host" is not known before running.

Comment: When do you know the host? Kinda confused.